# Which files to change in smoldot to design light client according to our need.?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, runtime, evm, light-client

I want to design  a light weight blockchain that is interoperable. Being light weight, it will be able to take part in consensus and create     new nodes without doing complex computations and wasting resources. This means, the blockchain will run on any mobile, tablet or laptop.
As already light client available , How can i change this smoldot repository to make my light client.
And which frameworks and language to considered?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up some stuff. The light client is called light because it only follows consensus. Meaning it isn't able to author any blocks. You still need validators that are able to produce new blocks.

Comment: Okay s but how  can we build light client same to smoldot